# How to reuse a ByteArrayInputStream?

Tags: java, inputstream

I have a piece of code that reads some binary data via an `InputStream` backed by a `ByteArrayInputStream`, like this

```
Object do(byte[] arr) {
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(arr);
    return conv(is);
```

I would like to avoid constructing new `ByteArrayInputStream` each call and instead just load the `arr` parameter into an existing member stream, however I can't find a simple way to do this. Is this or similar behaviour allowed or this against the recommended use of streams?

Comment: "I would like to avoid constructing new InputStream/ByteArrayInputStream objects each call ... " => Why? There is no need to reuse an input stream. Additionally, input streams are generally considered to be only readyble once.

Comment: For performance reasons, I don't want to read the same data over and over, just use the same object to read whatever data comes in

Comment: I don't see any performance issue by creating a new `ByteArrayInputStream` over resetting the backing byte array in it. You seem to have some other constraints in mind that you did not express in your question. I therefore vote to close it as unclear.

Comment: On your use of the [tag:java-stream] tag, it is intended for the java Stream api introduced in [tag:java-8], not for the use of i/o streams

Comment: *Why?*: Perhaps if one wants use the `ByteArrayInputStream` in a `ObjectInputStream()` and wants to feed it another object.  Because recreating a `ObjectInputStream()` will reset instance identities.  And because using a `PipedInputStream()` instead is cumbersome due to the nature of the internal buffer (i.e. deadlocks can happen if data is not fed by another thread).

Answer (score 1):

You can use mark()/reset() methods for this.